# Drop and re-calculate vertices M values for a polyline using ArcObjects

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I am trying to implement this logic for my C# project that it will remove the M values of all the vertices on a polyline, and then re-calibrate them.

There is another post out here asking a similar question. The difference is that post asked how to do it in ArcPy and I am wondering how I can do it using ArcObjects. The images below are taken from that post which show how you can do it in ArcMap using `Drop Measures` and `Set As Distance` on the targeted polyline.

Somebody in that post actually mentioned the use of Interface `IMSegmentation3`. Details of how to use that interface and code examples would be much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Some sample code on this [page](https://developers.arcgis.com/enterprise-sdk/api-reference/net/IMSegmentation2/).

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd, but I wonder which methods I should use? There are a bunch of them that seem to be doing similar stuff. Is CalibrateByDistance the one I should go for?